# error when using keras' sk-learn API

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

i'm learning keras these days, and i met an error when using scikit-learn API.Here are something maybe useful:

**ENVIRONMENT**:

```
python:3.5.2  
keras:1.0.5  
scikit-learn:0.17.1
```

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold


def read_db():
    "get prepared data from mysql."
    con_str = "mysql+mysqldb://root:0000@localhost/nbse?charset=utf8"
    engine = create_engine(con_str)
    data = pd.read_sql_table('data_ml', engine)
    return data

def nn_model():
    "create a model."
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=100, input_dim=105, activation='softplus'))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=1, input_dim=100, activation='softplus'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model

data = read_db()
y = data.pop('PRICE').as_matrix()
x = data.as_matrix()
model = nn_model()
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model, nb_epoch=2)
model.fit(x,y)  #something wrong here!
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/forecast/gridsearch.py", line 43, in <module>
    model.fit(x,y)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn.py", line 135, in fit
    **self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn.__call__))
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

the model works well without packaging with kerasRegressor, but i wanna using sk_learn's gridSearch after this, so i'm here for help. I tried but still have no idea.

**something maybe helpful:**

```
keras.warappers.scikit_learn.py  

class BaseWrapper(object):  


    def __init__(self, build_fn=None, **sk_params):
        self.build_fn = build_fn
        self.sk_params = sk_params
        self.check_params(sk_params)  


    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        '''Construct a new model with build_fn and fit the model according
        to the given training data.
    # Arguments
        X : array-like, shape `(n_samples, n_features)`
            Training samples where n_samples in the number of samples
            and n_features is the number of features.
        y : array-like, shape `(n_samples,)` or `(n_samples, n_outputs)`
            True labels for X.
        kwargs: dictionary arguments
            Legal arguments are the arguments of `Sequential.fit`

    # Returns
        history : object
            details about the training history at each epoch.
    '''

    if self.build_fn is None:
        self.model = self.__call__(**self.filter_sk_params(self.__call__))
    elif not isinstance(self.build_fn, types.FunctionType):
        self.model = self.build_fn(
            **self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn.__call__))
    else:
        self.model = self.build_fn(**self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn))

    loss_name = self.model.loss
    if hasattr(loss_name, '__name__'):
        loss_name = loss_name.__name__
    if loss_name == 'categorical_crossentropy' and len(y.shape) != 2:
        y = to_categorical(y)

    fit_args = copy.deepcopy(self.filter_sk_params(Sequential.fit))
    fit_args.update(kwargs)

    history = self.model.fit(X, y, **fit_args)

    return history
```

error occored in this line:

```
    self.model = self.build_fn(
        **self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn.__call__))
```

self.build_fn here is keras.models.Sequential

```
models.py  

class Sequential(Model):

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        if not self.built:
            self.build()
        return self.model.call(x, mask)
```

So, what's that x mean and how to fix this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[xiao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6825808/xiao), I ran into the same issue! Hopefully this helps:

## Background and The Issue

The [documentation for Keras](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/#wrappers-for-the-scikit-learn-api) states that, when implementing Wrappers for scikit-learn, there are two arguments. The first is the build function, which is a "callable function or class instance". Specifically, it states that:

> `build_fn` should construct, compile and return a Keras model, which will then be used to fit/predict. One of the following three values could be passed to build_fn:
>
> 1. A function
> 2. An instance of a class that implements the **call** method
> 3. None. This means you implement a class that inherits from either `KerasClassifier` or `KerasRegressor`. The **call** method of the present class will then be treated as the default build_fn.

In your code, you create the model, and then pass the model as the value for the argument `build_fn` when creating the `KerasRegressor` wrapper:

```
model = nn_model()
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model, nb_epoch=2)
```

Herein lies the issue. Rather than passing your `nn_model` **function** as the `build_fn`, you pass an actual instance of the Keras `Sequential` model. For this reason, when `fit()` is called, it cannot find the `call` method, because it is not implemented in the class you returned.

## Proposed Solution

What I did to make things work is pass the function as `build_fn`, rather than an actual model:

```
data = read_db()
y = data.pop('PRICE').as_matrix()
x = data.as_matrix()
# model = nn_model() # Don't do this!
# set build_fn equal to the nn_model function
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=nn_model, nb_epoch=2) # note that you do not call the function!
model.fit(x,y)  # fixed!
```

This is not the only solution (you could set `build_fn` to a class that implements the `call` method appropriately), but the one that worked for me. I hope it helps you!

Comment: @matsuninja Do you know how to pass parameters to the function? I would like to make a more generic `nn_model` function with different layer sizes and such parameters...

Comment: @Luis, in the example above, remember that the code inside of the nn_model function defines the model parameters (including layer sizes, etc.). My proposed solution (again, only one of a few alternatives) passes the function nn_model as the build_fn value. In order to set the model parameters, alter the code in the nn_model function; this is in fact what xiao does when defining the nn_model function. Hope that helps.

Comment: @matsuninja I solved it by setting a global variable to the number of nodes. I guess it is not possible to use an `nn_model` function which expects parameters in this approach...

Answer (score 0):

User-defined keyword arguments passed to `__init__()` that is to say, all keyword arguments that were given to `__init__()` will be passed to `model_build_fn` directly. For example, calling `KerasClassifier(myparam=10)` will result in a `model_build_fn(my_param=10)`

here's an example:

```
class MyMultiOutputKerasRegressor(KerasRegressor):
    
    # initializing
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        KerasRegressor.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        
    # simpler fit method
    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        KerasRegressor.fit(self, X, [y]*3, **kwargs)
```

(...)

```
def get_quantile_reg_rpf_nn(layers_shape=[50,100,200,100,50], inDim= 4, outDim=1, act='relu'):
          # do model stuff...
```

(...)
initialize the Keras regressor:

```
base_model = MyMultiOutputKerasRegressor(build_fn=get_quantile_reg_rpf_nn,
                                         layers_shape=[50,100,200,100,50], inDim= 4, 
                                         outDim=1, act='relu', epochs=numEpochs, 
                                         batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
```